# GIS Data from osm visual in google maps

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, google-maps

I have download from openstreetmap data for my project in a workshop i use den coordinates from a roads network ,but i have problem with visualization the cord in google maps same roads is not drawn on the roadσ but elsewhere map but is not for all roads , why i have this problem , i use in road table the pgrouting dikjstra algorithm same ways visualization corect others is not.
Is problem from data set of osm ?

Comment: Google maps does not use OSM data for its mapping, so it would be surprising if they completely agreed. Could you provide a more concrete example of somewhere where you have found an issue?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to understand your concern with some slightly better punctuation, and/or some examples. Can you try to give us more information to work with?

Comment: I have the osm data from a city roads in a table i use an dijstra algorithm to find routing but when i try to visualazation in google maps is not corect is show the path out of the roads . I can find any where data from the city , is anything i can make to make my self the data from the roads , for example from the google earth to export the coords of roads an make a table in postgresql with coords to use it for visualazation in google maps

Comment: Why don't you use Openstreetmap as background for the visualization?

Comment: because i make all the project with google java api 3 , is simple to change it to work in Openstreetmap as background for the visualization

Comment: Road data from different sources will always have small offsets to each other. Or are you talking about larger offsets, say more than two meters? Can you show us an example image?

Comment: Heare is an example http://postimg.org/image/ucc9aa8kf/.
Can i make a web application with openstreetmap, is has an javascript api ?

Comment: That's a typical offset you will have to accept for any data source. Google's roads will likewise have such offsets from their own aerial imagery in various places.

OpenStreetMap doesn't offer aerial imagery but you can of course use alternative java script libraries such as Leaflet and OpenLayers for creating interactive maps.

Comment: the Leaflet library can make webapp wich the user move live in the map and show his moving using gps ?